# Nginx reverse proxy configurations on multiple servers

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm currently in a situation in which I have server A which needs to be a reverse proxy for production server B (both Nginx). Server B is already available through the domain name and the file sites-available looks like this:

```
server {
   listen         [::]:80;
   server_name    my-domain.com;
   return         301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name my-domain.com;
    root /var/www/..../web;
    client_max_body_size 10M;

    location / {
            try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/.../web$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;

            }
 location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    alias /var/www/challenges/;
    try_files $uri =404;
    }
   ssl_certificate /...; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key ..; # managed by Certbot
}
```

My question is, should I let this file for what it is on server B and just point from server A to server B through proxy pass when the domain is transferred?

Comment: How do you refer to this new server after the proxy_pass? Is the server in same lan or different lan? Do you plan to keep the SSL certificate on both server?

Comment: It is preferable to have the SSL certificates on the reverse proxy server because it is easier to add new servers behind the reverse proxy

Comment: What about the domain name of this new server?

Comment: The domain name of server B needs to be transferred to server A which I can do easily but I want to avoid unnecessary downtime. So server B will be accessible through an IP address

Comment: What you can do in that case is, have a nginx config on Server A which just does the `proxy_pass`, you need to have a host entry for your own domain on the server A's `/etc/hosts` file, pointing to Server B IP and then use `proxy_pass https://example.com`, this will point. Before making the domain transfer you will need to make a local entry in your test machine and point to server A using the domain name and test if the proxying works fine or not